# Check to see if something is a model or collection in backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When you override backbone sync, both model/collection .save()/fetch() uses the same backbone sync method, so what is the best way to check if what Backbone.sync recieves is a model or a collection of models?

As an example:

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options){
  //Model here can be both a collection or a single model so
 if(model.isModel()) // there is no isModel or isCollection method
}
```

I suppose I am looking for a "safe" best practice, I could of course check for certain attributes or methods that only a model or a collection have, but it seems hackish, shouldn't there be a better obvious way? And there probably is I just couldn't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could also try `instanceof` like so:

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
  if (model instanceof Backbone.Model) {
    ...
  } else if (model instanceof Backbone.Collection) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

@fiskers7's answer works with deep extension :

```
        var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
            className : 'Item',
            size :10
        });

        var VerySmallItem = Item.extend({
            size :0.1
        });

        var item = new Item();
        var verySmall = new VerySmallItem();

        alert("item is Model ?" + (item instanceof Backbone.Model)); //true
        alert("verySmall is Model ?" + (verySmall instanceof Backbone.Model)); //true
```

Answer (score 2):

This is equally hackish, but a Backbone collection has a model property, and a model doesn't -- it is itself a model.

Perhaps a safer method is model.toJSON() and see if the result is an object or an array.  You're probably going to model.toJSON() in your custom Backbone.sync anyway, so though this is pretty computationally expensive, it would happen anyway.

Comment: Upvote because I was checking on the `length` property (only Collection... ?!?) yesterday in some quick coding! Checking on `model` is brilliant in comparison. Haha.

Comment: You guys shouldn't count on stuff like this because they may change in the future and break your code. Use the instanceof keyword as described :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how I feel about this because it seems a bit hackish, but I can't exactly think of why it would be super bad at the moment.

Definitely simple, and faster than an "instanceof" check (I'm assuming you won't name any other functions "isBBModel/Collection" on your objects?)

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.isBBCollection = function() { return false; }
Backbone.Model.prototype.isBBModel = function() { return true; }
Backbone.Collection.prototype.isBBCollection = function() { return true; }
Backbone.Collection.prototype.isBBModel = function() { return false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.getType = function() {
    return "Model";
}

Backbone.Collection.prototype.getType = function() {
    return "Collection";
}

if(model.getType() == "Model") {}
if(model.getType() == "Collection"){}
```

Comment: It's a very bad idea, almost impossible to maintain when application gets more complicated. And what happen if an object needs a getType() method that talks about a type of Car instead a type of Backbone Object ?

Comment: @NicolasZozol disagree. I don't see how this is hard to maintain and the 2nd point is simply unfair. You can call the above methods whatever you want. For example `getBackboneObjectType`, which will definitely not cause any naming conflicts.

Comment: The reason why this is bad, is it requires the implementer to keep track of object types contained in a 3rd party library, and create a new getType prototype every time a new type is introduced into future versions of Backbone.  Plus, you expose yourself to misspelling the types with no real easy way to detect it (since it's all being done via string comparisons.)  Using instanceof allows JavaScript compilers (like node.js) to detect any misspellings, and will fail compilation should object names change in an updated version of Backbone, making breaking changes easier to identify.